# set multiple return value for method declaration

Tags: c#, methods, svc

I have a function as below:

```
  public var UpdateMapFetcher(int stationID, int typeID)
```

I need this function to return either string or int.

My return value is set as below

```
 if (finaloutput == "System.String")
        {
            // param1[i] = Convert.ChangeType(typeID_New.ToString(), typeof(string));
            returnvalue = returnvalue.ToString();
            return returnvalue;
        }
        else if (finaloutput == "System.Int32")
        {
            int a=0;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(returnvalue);
            return a;
        }
```

How to have either one data type as return value in dynamic environment.

Comment: Can you better describe why that is what you need? (You can always return an `object` but I think maybe you should rethink a bit design)

Comment: `var` is just "compiler, please figure out the correct data type and put it here". It still has to be determined *at compile time*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My intuition tells me, that you are trying to convert string value to some type. In that case you can use:

```
public T UpdateMapFetcher<T>(int stationID)
{
    //var someValue = "23";
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(someValue, typeof(T));
}
//then
var typed = UpdateMapFetcher<int>(6);
```

---

In case you don't know T, you can use mapping (0-int, 1-string, etc.):

```
public object UpdateMapFetcher(int stationID, int type)
{
    var typeMap = new []{ typeof(int), typeof(string)};
    //var someValue = "23";
    return Convert.ChangeType(someValue, typeMap[type]);
}
//then
var untyped = UpdateMapFetcher(6, 0/*0 is int*/);
if (untyped.GetType() == typeof(int))
{ /*is int*/
}
```

---

Another solution is to use implicit conversions:

```
public class StringOrInt
{
    private object value;
    public ValueType Type { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator StringOrInt(string value)
    {
        return new StringOrInt()
        {
            value = value,
            Type = ValueType.String
        };
    }
    public static implicit operator StringOrInt(int value)
    {
        return new StringOrInt()
        {
            value = value,
            Type = ValueType.Int
        };
    }
    public static implicit operator int(StringOrInt obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.value;
    }
    public static implicit operator string(StringOrInt obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.value;
    } 
}
public enum ValueType
{
    String,
    Int
}
```

And then (simplified):

```
public static StringOrInt UpdateMapFetcher(int stationID, int typeID)
{
    if (typeID == 0)
        return "Text";
    return 23;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = UpdateMapFetcher(1, 1);
    if (result.Type == ValueType.String) { }//can check before
    int integer = result;//compiles, valid
    string text = result;//compiles, fail at runtime, invalid cast      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can return an object. You'd have to subsequently check for types in your consuming method. I assume that won't be a problem in your usecase.

your method signature is therefore:

```
public object UpdateMapFetcher(int stationID, int typeID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option of using the [out keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx), which permits you to accept both into variables and check after the function has been called.

```
public void UpdateMapFetcher(int stationID, int typeID, out int intValue, out string strValue)

// or int return val and out string value

public int UpdateMapFetcher(int stationID, int typeID, out string strValue)
```

With the use appearing something like this:

```
int intVal;
string strVal;

UpdateMapFetcher(stationID, typeID, out intVal, out strVal);

if (strVal != null) 
{ 
    doSomethingWithString(strVal); 
}
else
{
    doSomethingWithInt(intVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I would just return a Tuple, with string being non-null indicating string value to use, and null as indicator for int return

```
public Tuple<string, int> UpdateMapFetcher(int stationID, int typeID) {
    if (finaloutput == "System.String")
    {
        // param1[i] = Convert.ChangeType(typeID_New.ToString(), typeof(string));
        returnvalue = returnvalue.ToString();
        return new Tuple<string, int>(returnvalue, 0);
    }
    else if (finaloutput == "System.Int32")
    {
        int a=0;
        a = Convert.ToInt32(returnvalue);
        return new Tuple<string, int>(null, a);
    }

}
```

On consumer side

```
var rc = UpdateMapFetcher( .... );

if (rc.Item1 != null) {
    // code to use string value
} else {
   // code to use int value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would choose to return an `object` of new `class` which might look like this:

```
class Result {

    public string StringValue { get; }

    public string Int32Value { get; }

    public bool IsString { get; }

    public bool IsInt32 { get; }

    public Result(string value) {
        StringValue = value;
        IsString = true;
    }

    public Result(int value) {
        Int32Value = value;
        IsInt32 = true;
    }
}
```

This way you can check which `Type` is it by using `Isxxx` property. You can also enhance this with validation in value `get`ers. F. e., for `string` it might look like this:

```
public string StringValue {
    get {
        if (IsString)
            return m_stringValue;
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Value is not a string.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do *exactly* that, but there are several ways to do more or less what you want. You'd probably be better off change the design a little though.

Two ideas:

- Either change your code to use two different methods, and call each of them as needed instead.
- ..Or return an object, which you can cast however you like..
- ..Or, use a generic method with `TypeDescriptor`, like the following.

Note that we here convert the value to string first even if it was an int, since we can then use a common method `ConvertFromString()` to convert it to whatever type `T` was.

```
public T UpdateMapFetcher<T>(int stationID, int typeID) {
    // To allow parsing to the generic type T:
    var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    if(converter != null)
    {
        return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(returnvalue.ToString());
    }    
    else
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = MyExtensions.UpdateMapFetcher<string>(1, 2);
```

or:

```
var result = MyExtensions.UpdateMapFetcher<int>(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return Object and cast to type which you want.

```
public Object UpdateMapFetcher(int stationID, int typeID)

if (finaloutput == "System.String")
        {
            // param1[i] = Convert.ChangeType(typeID_New.ToString(), typeof(string));
            returnvalue = returnvalue.ToString();
            return returnvalue;
        }
        else if (finaloutput == "System.Int32")
        {
            int a=0;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(returnvalue);
            return a;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A type that can contain either one type or another is usually called (unsurprisingly) `Either`. It is a special case of a [*sum type*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), basically a *discriminated union*, *tagged union*, or *disjoint union* with exactly two cases (instead of an arbitrary number).

Unfortunately, there does not exist an implementation of an `Either` type in the standard libraries, but there are plenty of implementations to be found on Google, GitHub, and elsewhere … and porting one of the existing implementations from e.g. Haskell or Scala isn't that hard, either.

It looks a bit like this (forgive my code, I don't actually know C♯ that well):

```
using System;

abstract class Either<A, B>
{
    public abstract bool IsLeft { get; }
    public abstract bool IsRight { get; }
    public abstract A Left { get; }
    public abstract B Right { get; }
    public abstract A LeftOrDefault { get; }
    public abstract B RightOrDefault { get; }
    public abstract void ForEach(Action<A> action);
    public abstract void ForEach(Action<B> action);
    public abstract void ForEach(Action<A> leftAction, Action<B> rightAction);

    private sealed class L : Either<A, B>
    {
        private A Value { get; }
        public override bool IsLeft => true;
        public override bool IsRight => false;
        public override A Left => Value;
        public override B Right { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); } }
        public override A LeftOrDefault => Value;
        public override B RightOrDefault => default(B);
        public override void ForEach(Action<A> action) => action(Value);
        public override void ForEach(Action<B> action) {}
        public override void ForEach(Action<A> leftAction, Action<B> rightAction) => leftAction(Value);

        internal L(A value) { Value = value; }
    }

    private sealed class R : Either<A, B>
    {
        private B Value { get; }
        public override bool IsLeft => false;
        public override bool IsRight => true;
        public override A Left { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); } }
        public override B Right => Value;
        public override A LeftOrDefault => default(A);
        public override B RightOrDefault => Value;
        public override void ForEach(Action<A> action) {}
        public override void ForEach(Action<B> action) => action(Value);
        public override void ForEach(Action<A> leftAction, Action<B> rightAction) => rightAction(Value);

        internal R(B value) { Value = value; }
    }

    public static Either<A, B> MakeLeft(A value) => new L(value);
    public static Either<A, B> MakeRight(B value) => new R(value);
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        int intResult;
        var result = int.TryParse(input, out intResult) ? Either<int, string>.MakeLeft(intResult) : Either<int, string>.MakeRight(input);
        result.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine("You passed me the integer one less than " + ++r), r => Console.WriteLine(r));
    }
}
```